# How to set background-image in react? (sass)

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have structure like this and I want to set background url but I keep getting errors like "the server responded with a status of 404". What tools should I use to be able to link local images to project?

`project
│

└──src
|   |   index.html
|   |   index.js
│   │   icons
│   │   images
|   │

│   └───stylesheets
│       │   files.scss
│

│

└───public
    │   index_bundle.js`

Comment: how did you set your routes and server? are you using Express? 404 means the static resources is not hooked up

Comment: @Yuhao I'm not using Express, I want to use webpack to load my files from images folder

Comment: Im using webpack to load static files too. So the issue is the webpack set up. Can you post your webpack.config file

Comment: And also might be your route to <image src=""/> is wrong. try this part as well

Comment: I fixed this problem myself. I've installed file-loader and set ip up like this  {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: "file-loader"
      }